# Rails 4 - render array value one by one using postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

I'm using Postgres as database and making use of Postgres array support that comes out of the box with Rails 4.

I have a model called Recipe and it contains `t.text :steps, array: true` array attribute.
I want to render this array attribute in a text field separated by each value.

I've tried the following but I get error `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`.

```
<% params[:steps].each do |step_id| %>
  <%= text_field_tag '[step][]', step_id %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: post your controller also, you should rather so something like @receipe.steps.each rather than params[:steps] as params store session params and request params, not the object itself

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 4 - how to render array in text field per value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27886760/rails-4-how-to-render-array-in-text-field-per-value)

Comment: @Swistaku Hi, thanks for your input. Do I still need to have @recipe.steps even if my form helper already references @recipe? I have `form_for @recipe that wraps this`

Comment: @Swistaku Hi, text_field_tag helper doesn't seem to work. Would you be able to tell me which form helper I should be using that will display value in text field and updating this value can also be persisted?