# Rails 4 - how to render array in text field per value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql

I'm using Postgres as database and making use of an array type column that is supported in Rails 4.

I have a model called Recipe and it contains `t.text :steps, array: true` array attribute.
I want to render this array attribute in a text field separated by each value.

I've tried the following but I get error `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass`.

```
<% params[:steps].each do |step_id| %>
  <%= text_field_tag '[step][]', step_id %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: that error means that your `params[:steps]` is empty

Comment: Try `<% (params[:steps] || []).each do |step_id| %>`. Give an empty array to `each` if `params[:steps]` is empty.

Comment: @HarshGupta Thanks. It removes the error but this renders invisible html that is commented out. How can I still render empty text field if array is empty?

Comment: Try `<% (params[:steps] || ['']).each do |step_id| %>`. Just pass an array with one empty string.

Comment: @HarshGupta Hi, that seems to solve the invisible field issue, thanks. I still have `text_field_tag` form helper that doesn't persist input data. Would you be able to give me any idea what form helper I should be using?